# Security Issues:Maintaining HTTP session only in cookies

Tags: security, web-applications, session-cookies

Can somebody explain me the security issues which might arrise(also how) if I maintain HTTP session only in cookie(s)?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean, please? The few words "maintain session only in cookies" does not give a clear enough understanding of what you are trying to achieve and what kind of concerns you have. Please describe in more detail your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can code a session management by use of cookies only. It will require many pieces to manage session information.
Any flow if managing cookie expiration time stamp, secure cookies, session id generation etc can cause issues such as -

- cookies can be stolen & reused
- manipulation of cookies can cause privilege escalations & unauthorized
  access

Answer (score 0):

Well,  per se sessions are insecure, you Open a hole in your application for someone having a Shared Secret. But thats tolerable. Problems arise, when someone gets your Session id. To avoid this, your ids should be of uuid-quality (really random) and as short-Term as possible.

Also to consider: if someone is able to insert JS into your Domain ( for which the cookie is valid), he/she is able to read your cookie and gain acces to someone's session.

For actions involving security relevant stuff (transferring money, changing e-mail/password) you should ask for the password again, to verify the users session.

Clicking the lockout button should not only destroy your local cookie, but also the session one the server, so even if the cookie has been read, the session can be destroyed.